# how to dedicate a processor core to an application

Tags: windows-vista

I have a core i7 running windows vista and i want to dedicate a core to ONE application.
i mean i want that and only that application use that core(which in intel core i7 each core is 2 threads)
Some people might suggest setting the affinity but id have to deselect all other applications from using that core. I was thinking if there is a simpler way (a code or something else) or a software i can use to do this.

If there is such a feature in win7 please let me know cuz i'll soon switch to win7.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should post it on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

The first question you should ask is "What if every application did this"?

That should be enough to tell you that being allowed to monopolize a core for yourself isn't a good thing.

If you're doing a lot of heavy lifting on the CPU, then the scheduler will move other processes onto another core if it needs to. If it doesn't, then your process will be fine to co-exist with whatever else the scheduler puts there.